# Почему я получаю [object%20Object] c аякса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Почему в представление приходит словарь с `[object%20Object]` .По идее, должен быть словарь, который я создал в скрипте...

Если убрать `processData` - получаю ошибку *Illegal invocation*

```
$(document).on('click', '.more_credits_first', function () {
  var button = $(this)
  var show = $(button).data('show');
  var code = $('.bg-white > .nav-item > .nav-link.active')

  var data = {
    'show': show,
    'code': code
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(23)
    }
  })
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что отправляете, то и получаете. зы: вы уверны, что `contentType` следует в `false` устанавливать? зы2: возможно вам `$.getJson()` уместнее будет?

Comment: не помогло...((

Comment: Где вы видите `[object%20Object]`?

Comment: _Почему в представление приходит словарь с [object%20Object]_ - как ты проверяешь?

Comment: @Grundy `print(request.GET)`

Comment: где ты это вызываешь? Что за функция `print`?

Comment: на сервере в Джанго.

Comment: Проверь на вкладке `Network` или `Сеть` в браузере какой конкретно запрос посылается.

Comment: @Grundy добавил скрин запроса.

Comment: не заполняй свойство processData, то есть вместо `$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(23)
    }
  })` выполняй `$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(23)
    }
  })`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` не пробовали?

Comment: @Grundy ошибка _Illegal invocation_

Comment: @Александр пробовал - не подходит.

Comment: @РустамГимранов указал - без изменений (здесь url необязателен вообще, насколько я знаю)

Comment: @РустамГимранов словарь - `{show: "show", code: r.fn.init(0)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = {
  // @NB: Здесь должны быть строки, а не объекты `jquery`.
  'show': $(this).data('show'),
  // @NB: Здесь должны быть строки, а не объекты `jquery`.
  'code': $('.bg-white > .nav-item > .nav-link.active').text()
}

// Добавьте в ваш вопрос, что за данные здесь формируются.
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', // по умолчанию GET
  url: 'ссылка/к/ресурсу', // если не указать запрос будет на текущую страницу.
  data: data, // передаваемые данные. GET параметры добавляются к ссылке.
  cache: false, // запрошенные страницы не будут закешированы браузером.
  // dataType: 'json', // чтобы jQuery распарсил `success` ответ как JSON.
  // processData: false, // чтобы jQuery не обрабатывал отправляемые данные.
  contentType: false, // чтобы jQuery не передавал в заголовке поле `Content-Type` совсем.
  success: function(response) {
    renderTable(response);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert('error');

    console.log({
      [error.status]: error
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Это могло быть из-за того, что в переменной code я сохранил объект?..

Comment: Странно, не могу повторно воспроизвести эту ошибку. А так да: параметры `data` при GET запросе к ссылке добавляются, когда по умолчанию `processData: true`, а вы туда JQuery объект вместо текста, при этом указываете, чтобы он эти данные не обрабатывал `processData: false`.